# Django View Nested Tuple Calculation

Tags: python, django

I am trying to calculate the timedelta in a Generic View but I don't understand how to go though the tuple and do the calculation I am looking.

The query I am running is

```
sla_list = self.object_list.filter(types__name="Unplanned").filter(service__sla=True).values_list('service__name', 'end_out', 'start_out')
```

An example of the return is.

```
(u'Peoplesoft', datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 12, 1, 57, tzinfo=(UTC)), datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 11, 19, 25, tzinfo=(UTC)))
```

I had the calculation in a Model Method and it was working but for the calculation that I want to do on the timedelta I though that it should be moved into the View.

The model method I was using was

```
timedelta = self.end_out - self.start_out
timedelta = timedelta.total_seconds()
timedelta = time.strftime('%H:%M', time.gmtime(timedelta))
```

Any ideas would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: timedelta is the name of a datetime module/object, so you should probably use a different variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sla_list` contains the 3 values you asked for, so `sla_list[1]` is the end_out value, while `start_out` is `sla_list[2]`.

Simply apply your calculation to those two values:

```
timedelta = sla_list[1] - sla_list[2]
timedelta = '%02d:%02d' % divmod(timedelta.total_seconds(), 60)
```

I replaced your `time.gmtime(timedelta)` and `strftime` dance with a simpler method using the [`divmod()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#divmod); all you need to do is turn the total number of seconds into hours (seconds divided by 60) and remaining seconds (seconds modulo 60), after all.

If you need sum the timedeltas per `service__name` entry, order by by that entry and use the [`itertools.groupby` callable](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to calculate your sums quickly and efficiently:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

sla_list = self.object_list.filter(types__name="Unplanned").filter(service__sla=True).order_by('service__name').values_list('service__name', 'end_out', 'start_out')
sla_deltas = {}
for name, entries in groupby(sla_list, itemgetter(0)):
    sla_deltas[name] = sum(end - start for name, end, start in entries)
```

The `groupby` function gives you sub-lists with matching `sla__name` values, we simply calculate the `datetime.timedelta` for each entry and use `sum()` to calculate the total timedelta.

Comment: I got that part but I am not sure how to implement it in my code.  Once I return the timedelta I want to find all service__name that are the same and do a sum of the timedelte.

Comment: @Ross: That is *far* from clear from your question. In your post you are asking how to access the datetime objects in a tuple, not how to combine the timedeltas for matching service names.

Comment: @Ross: I've updated my answer to sum all timedeltas for all a given `service__name`. Next time, please make it clear in your answer what you expect :-)

Comment: Thanks.. First time I posted.  My brain and fingers don't always work together.  I am trying this now.  Thanks again.